# How to parse html to get values in array using php

Tags: php, html, arrays

So I'm trying to parse data using JS. Here is the HTML code which I have. There are more than 10000 records to parse. Just mentioning a few for clarification:

```
 $str = '<ul>
       <li>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/profile/shrey">Shrey Chathly</a>
          <p> shrey@yahoo.com</p>
          <p> 9910212121</p>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/profile/neminath">Neminath</a>
          <p> 9818505051</p>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/profile/mohan">Mohan</a>
          <p> Mohan@yahoo.co.in</p>
          <p> 9111502287</p>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/profile/naina">Naina</a>
          <p> naina@gmail.com</p>
          <p> 9818505001</p>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/profile/mohan">Rakesh</a>
          <p> 9111502222</p>
       </li>
    </ul>';
```

I have tried to do that with:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a'); //DOMNodeList
$p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p'); //DOMNodeList

foreach($a as $NodeHeader){
  $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
}

$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach($p as $sNodeDetail) {
  $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
  $i = $i + 1;
  $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;      


 }

  //print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML);
  // out put
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => shrey@yahoo.com
                    [1] => 9910212121
                    [2] => 9818505051
                    [3] => Mohan@yahoo.co.in
                    [4] => 9111502287
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => naina@gmail.com
                    [1] => 9818505001
                    [2] => 9111502222
                )
        )
```

I want output like :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Shrey Chathly
                [1] => shrey@yahoo.com
                [2] => 9910212121
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Neminath
                [1] => 
                [2] => 9818505051
            )
         [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Mohan
                [1] => mohan@yahoo.co.in
                [2] => 9111502287
            ) 
          [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => Naina
                [1] => naina@gmail.com
                [2] => 9818505001
            ) 
          [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => Rakesh
                [1] => 
                [2] => 9111502222
            )      
    )
```

I'm not able to find a way to achieve the expected output.
Please help me.  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Shrey Chathly
            [1] => shrey@yahoo.com
            [2] => 9910212121
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Neminath
            [1] => 
            [2] => 9818505051
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mohan
            [1] => Mohan@yahoo.co.in
            [2] => 9111502287
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Naina
            [1] => naina@gmail.com
            [2] => 9818505001
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rakesh
            [1] => 
            [2] => 9111502222
        )
)
```

can be achieved like so:

```
<?php
$str = '<ul><li><a href="https://www.example.com/profile/shrey">Shrey Chathly</a><p> shrey@yahoo.com</p><p> 9910212121</p></li><li><a href="https://www.example.com/profile/neminath">Neminath</a><p> 9818505051</p></li><li><a href="https://www.example.com/profile/mohan">Mohan</a><p> Mohan@yahoo.co.in</p><p> 9111502287</p></li><li><a href="https://www.example.com/profile/naina">Naina</a><p> naina@gmail.com</p><p> 9818505001</p></li><li><a href="https://www.example.com/profile/mohan">Rakesh</a><p> 9111502222</p></li></ul>';
    
$data = null;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
foreach($elements as $key => $element) {
  foreach($element->getElementsByTagName('a') as $valueA) {
    $data[$key][] = trim($valueA->textContent);
  }
  
  $pValues = $element->getElementsByTagName('p');
  if(count($pValues) >= 2) {
      $data[$key][] = trim($pValues[0]->textContent);
      $data[$key][] = trim($pValues[1]->textContent);
  } elseif (count($pValues) == 1) {
      $data[$key][] = null;
      $data[$key][] = trim($pValues[0]->textContent);
  }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

[Play with it online here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0970593bcc1b319cc7de3386c39c6662aad59bdb](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0970593bcc1b319cc7de3386c39c6662aad59bdb):

Comment: caramba, Thank you very much. It's working. Please mark the answer as solved

Comment: @Mohan thanks for your reply. Only the questioner (in this case it is you) can accept the answer. More details can be found here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)